# Is it possible to update a SQL ResultSet in Java for local use without modifying the DB?

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to use `ResultSet.updateDouble()` to modify a `ResultSet` for some local processing. I don't actually want to modify the underlying database.

My hope was that using `updateDouble()` would make the changes to the `ResultSet` object but not update the actual database as I never call `ResultSet.updateRow()`.

I'm finding that just calling the update method doesn't actually have an effect on the column fields in the `ResultSet` object.

Is there a way to modify a `ResultSet` for local use, or should I just copy the relevant data to an `ArrayList` and work with that?

Comment: If the database connection is still alive while you perform the operations, then execute a rollback after finishing your operations.

Comment: Why do you need to update it anyway? I usually copy the data first, then edit them.

Comment: you can set autocommit to false (connection.setAutoCommit(false)), remember to set it to true once you're done.

Comment: I think I will copy the data first; there's no good reason to try and abuse the ResultSet. Also, thanks for the other suggestions but in my case I don't have a reason to leave the connection open during processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to answer this question is to do an experiment.  Perhaps you should have asked the question, then conducted your own experiment and answered it yourself.

I suspect it is possible to do it as you describe, without calling a rollback as one of the comments suggested, but I would recommend against it.

Often times we are tempted to take the most expedite way of doing something, but often time that leads to hard to find faults.  Take the time and do it right, construct the array list as you suggest.